# Drag and Drop: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, blob

I am creating a speed reader which first takes in a PDF and converts it to text. I have a drag and drop area set up and a button that goes into the user's files to select.

The file select works and I am able to read in the file but when I try to use the drag and drop it doesn't work and I get an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have (I am still fairly new to JS):

```
<!--drag and drop file upload-->
<div class="bottom">
    <div id="drop-area">
        <form class="my-form">
            <p id="drop-text">Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</p>

            <input type="file" id="fileElem" name="fileElem" multiple accept=".pdf" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" />

            <progress id="progress-bar" max=100 value=0></progress>

            <div><label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label></div>
        </form>
        <div id="gallery"></div>
    </div>
    <div><button class="button" id="submit" onclick="convert()">Process PDF</button></div>
</div>

...
<script type="text/javascript">
    let dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area')

    ;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
        dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
    })

    function preventDefaults(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    ;['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
        dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
    })

    ;['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
        dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
    })

...

    dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false)

    function handleDrop(e) {
        let dt = e.dataTransfer
        let files = dt.files

        handleFiles(files)
    }

    function handleFiles(files) {
        files = [...files]
        initializeProgress(files.length) // <- Add this line
        files.forEach(uploadFile)
        files.forEach(previewFile)
    }

    //pdf reading
    function convert() {
        var fr=new FileReader();
        var pdff = new Pdf2TextClass();
        fr.onload=function(){
            pdff.pdfToText(fr.result, null, (text) => { document.getElementById('full-text').innerText += text; });
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('fileElem').files[0])
    }
```

As I have troubleshooted I've come to the conclusion that I am missing something in the handleDrop function.

[image]

Error 1: when I drag and drop a file.

Error 2: when I try to process it.

Error 3: when I select file.

Next section: working processing of selected file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote like that and run it.

```
  if (reader.readAsDataURL && uploadFile instanceof Blob) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
     }
```